# How to hide Textbox Keyboard when "Done / Return" Button is pressed Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I created a Text Field in Interface Builder.  I set it's "Return Key" to Done.  This is a one line only input (so it wont need multiple lines).

How do I hide the virtual keyboard when the user taps the done button?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Implement the delegate method `UITextFieldDelegate`, then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.yourIBtextField.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: The part that I was missing was adding <UITextViewDelegate> to the interface in the *.h file.  Once I added that, this code worked without issue.  Hope that helps someone else out!

Comment: In this situation <UITextFieldDelegate> is required.

Comment: You can also connect the delegate from the storyboard (xib), if you drag connection from the textField to the viewController representation. That way you don't have to write the line from viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 9):

UITextView does not have any methods which will be called when the user hits the return key.

Even then if you want to do this, implement the textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: method of UITextViewDelegate and in that check if the replacement text is \n, hide the keyboard.

There might be other ways but I am not aware of any.

Make sure you declare support for the UITextViewDelegate protocol.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This resets my hidden settings for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: can you please provide more details, like which kind of hidden setting ??

Answer (score 1):

Make category on UIViewController with next method

```
- (void)hideKeyboard
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
                                               to:nil
                                             from:nil
                                         forEvent:nil];
}
```