# Hiding Keyboard by pressing return when editing text in an UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

My app is running in UIWebView .. now when I click the return button in my keyboard when I'm editing a textfield in HTML page, I want the keyboard to disappear ... I went through some questions in Stack Overflow like [I can not hide keyboard by pressing return key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116022/i-can-not-hide-keyboard-by-pressing-return-key) and [How to hide Textbox Keyboard when "Done / Return" Button is pressed Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965357/how-to-hide-textbox-keyboard-when-done-return-button-is-pressed-xcode-4-2) but none of them is working for me.

Since , I can't set `textfield.delegate = self` (as I'm only editing the text fields when they are loaded via `UIWebView`) , I'm setting `mywebview.delegate = self` and as expected , it ain't working. Please help !!!! Also I can't use `textFieldShouldReturn()` method since the text field is inside an HTML ...

Comment: you need to handle this, using javascript or webpage event handling.

Comment: can you explain ??? thank you

Comment: sorry, but i don't have deep knowldege of this, but you need to see. jQuery mobile. it will be helpful.

Comment: Please give a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970848/uiwebview-customize-return-key

Comment: @Monikanta thank you so much :) this link looks like it'll definitely help me :) i'll let you know if it works ^_^